# Can we measure renormalized mass in QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, renormalization

Due to QFT books, we measure pole mass(physical mass) in experiments.
From the Lagrangian point of view, renormalized mass is a parameter(in MS bar or some similar renormalization scheme that has an explicit renormalization scale)

We fix renormalized parameters ( renormalized mass, renormalized couplings and ...) at specific energy scale by experiments.

But the problem is that how do we measure renormalized mass? beacuase in any expriment we measure pole mass which is scale independent

For other renormalized parameters, I have no problem.

Comment: I asked a closely related question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/402496/what-is-the-physical-meaning-of-the-overline-mathrmms-mass). Didn't get any answers, though.

Comment: Thanks Dan Yand, I am familiar with on-shell scheme that all quantities are expressed in term of physical mass and couplings. Are you saying that renormalized parameters are not measurable? My problem is about mass parameter, as I understand other couplings can be measured(or defined ) when we do experiments at different energy scales and can be compared with each other, but I am confused about renormalized mass, because any expriment measure pole mass instead of renormalized mass. Can we check renormalization group equation for mass parameters experimentally?

Comment: @knzhou, Can you understand the problem? I can't write comment on the pages that a curiousmind have mentioned. Comments on that page are not about how we measure renormalized mass