On-shell renormalization schemes, running couplings and grand unification
In dimensional regularization with minimal subtraction schemes (like MS or $\overline{\text{MS}}$), dimensional analysis mandates the introduction of an arbitrary dimensionful quantity $\mu$. By demanding that physical observables remain independent of $\mu$, we derive that the renormalized coupling parameters must run with $\mu$, leading to the renormalization group equations.
However, in the on-shell renormalization scheme, counterterms are tailored to absorb all $\mu$-dependence, and parameters are fixed at physical masses and momenta. In this setup, the scale $\mu$ effectively disappears from the calculations, and there doesn't seem to be an explicit notion of couplings running with the energy scale.
This raises the following question:
If the concept of running coupling constants is dependent on the renormalization scheme, how can it be considered a physically meaningful phenomenon?
In other words, practitioners often refer to the running of couplings as a physical effect, crucial, for instance, in predicting gauge coupling unification in GUTs. How do we reconcile the apparent scheme dependence of running couplings with their role in making physical predictions? In particular, how can one describe gauge coupling unification in the on-shell scheme, which lacks a notion of running coupling?
Edit: My question aims to reconcile how physical predictions (specifically, gauge coupling unification) can be made in schemes where the coupling does not explicitly run with the energy scale, such as the on-shell scheme. Question [1], in contrast, accepts the reality of the running coupling parameters and deals with technical aspects of higher-order coefficients of the beta function and their scheme dependence.
[1] Dependence by the renormalization scheme in the beta function coefficents in QCD

The baffling concept of "running with renormalization scale $\mu$" has unfortunately been peddled around for years. See here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/436173/

see also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/311843/84967

This question is similar to: Dependence by the renormalization scheme in the beta function coefficents in QCD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@ConnorBehan I think my question is quite different because it deals specifically with on-shell renormalization schemes, in which there is no residual $\mu$-dependence and thus no notion of running in the sense of the other question. I've edited the OP (and the title) to reflect that.

There is no scheme that will tell you that couplings don't run. If you don't have the fake parameter $\mu$ in the Lagrangian, you will still need to pick a scale where correlation functions should take on prescribed values and use that scale to define your counterterms. The usual analysis of the Callan-Symanzik equation then goes through and leads to a beta function. See P&S chapter 12.

@ConnorBehan I'm not sure why you're saying that because in the on-shell renormalization scheme there is clearly no $\mu$-dependence. The couplings are indeed determined by a choice of reference momentum, but this is conceptually distinct from the arbitrary parameter $\mu$ which is used in gauge coupling unification arguments. In any case, I think I have clearly explained why this question is distinct from the one you quoted.

I'll vote to reopen but I don't know which GUT calculation would have problems. The ones I've seen are based on the beta function. Beta functions for QCD in the on-shell scheme are indeed unknown but this is only because of confinement. It has nothing to do with the on-shell scheme being based on a conceptually distinct type of scale. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.2199 for the on-shell beta function of QED.
