# Are the infinities "cut off" in quantum field theory not considered a defect of the theory anymore? If not, why not?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I was reading Dirac's Directions in Physics and he talks about how he is not satisfied with the renormalization process. He believed it was a major flaw in quantum field theory. Is this still a tenable view? Is renomalization understood differently today or are we just more acclimated to it so we don't question it anymore out of habit?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/375209/2451

Comment: It is understood differently due to Wilson and Polchinski.