# What's the exact relationship between the scale $Q$ at which parameters are probed and the "fake parameter" $\mu$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

It is well known that couplings change depending on the scale $Q$ at they are measured. This effect is experimentally [well documented](https://www.science20.com/a_quantum_diaries_survivor/run_alpha_strong_run-150633):

[image]

From a theoretical point of view, the running $\alpha_S(\mu)$ can be calculated using the renormalized group equations. However, it is regularly argued that the parameter $\mu$ appears here is a "[fake parameter](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf)", has no meaning and can always be chosen at will. In particular, it is [argued](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/ms-qft-DRAFT.pdf) that we can use the fact that "*physical observables must be independent of the fake parameter $\mu$ to figure out how the lagrangian parameters $m$ and $g$ must change with $\mu$.*"

The renormalized group equations that we find this way are then regularly used to calculate the running of parameters like $\alpha_S$:

[image]

How does this fit together? In particular, what's the exact relationship between the *measured* energy dependence of parameters and the running of parameters with the fake parameter $\mu$?

**Or formulated differently, if the renormalization group equations encode the dependence on the "fake parameter" $\mu$, which equations describe the dependence on the physical energy scale $Q$?**

*(I'm aware that there are lots of related questions, but none of them seemed to answer this question unambiguously.)*

Comment: I've asked a few questions about this, which I guess you saw -- is there something specifically wrong with the answers to them? They satisfied me back when I had the same question.

Comment: Yes, I think I've read all of them. My problem is why it's regularly emphasized that $\mu$ is an arbitrary parameter and, on the other hand, why then people are interested in how parameters run with $\mu$. The reason seems to be that parameters are indeed scale dependent as can be measured in experiments. But the physical scale $Q$ at which a parameter is probed is not equal to $\mu$. So I'm trying to pin down the exact relationship between the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178754/50583

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if the renormalization group equations encode the dependence on the "fake parameter" $\mu$, which equations describe the dependence on the physical energy scale Q?

Let's look at a (oversimplified) case of running (where Q is the measurable probing energy (momentum) in a realistic scattering process),
$$
g(Q) = g_{\mu} + ln(\frac{Q}{\mu}),
$$
which is the solution to the differential equation
$$
\frac{dg}{d(lnQ)} = 1,
$$
with the initial condition
$$
g|_{Q=\mu} = g_{\mu}.
$$

Equivalently, the above logarithmic $g(Q)$ can be viewed as the solution to a different differential equation (the garden variety renormalization group equation)
$$
\frac{dg}{d(ln\mu)} = -1,
$$
with the initial condition
$$
g|_{\mu=Q} = g_{\mu}.
$$
The first differential equation (of $\frac{dg}{d(lnQ)}$) interprets the running as "g running with the probing/scattering energy (momentum) Q" and the second differential equation (of $\frac{dg}{d(ln\mu)}$, beta function in the usual parlance) interprets the running as "g running with renormalization scale $\mu$". Most text books take the second view, while I prefer the first. Nonetheless, they depict the same underlying physics.

The parameter $\mu$ is "fake" in the sense that, you can fix the solution of the differential equation of $\frac{dg}{d(lnQ)}$ with the initial condition set at $\mu'$, rather than at $\mu$,
$$
g(Q) = g_{\mu'} + ln(\frac{Q}{\mu'}),
$$
where
$$
g|_{Q=\mu'} = g_{\mu'} = g_{\mu} + ln(\frac{\mu'}{\mu}).
$$

In other words, the "fake parameter" $\mu$ is merely an arbitrary anchor point to frame the initial condition. Nothing more, nothing less!